# Стирается невидимое содержимое ячейки

Tags: javascript, html

я делаю судоку. Это поле 9х9, в каждое из которых можно вставить цифры. Каждая ячейка таблицы имеет следующий код:

```
<!--Класс ячейки-->
<td class="game-cell" onclick="cellClick(this)">
                            <!--Невидимые символы (невидимость задается в style.css)-->
                            <div class="pencil-grid">
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-1">
                                    1</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-2">
                                    2</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-3">
                                    3</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-4">
                                    4</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-5">
                                    5</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-6">
                                    6</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-7">
                                    7</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-8">
                                    8</div>
                                <div
                                    class="pencil-grid-cell pencil-grid-cell-9">
                                    9</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

Но при клике на ячейку и присвоения ей значения, у меня исчезают все классы с именем
pencil-grid-cell. Вот код, который делает это.

```
/** 
    @description ставит на поле нажатую цифру
                    сохраняет последняя нажатую клавишу
    @param {event} e, объект, по которому была нажата ЛКМ
    @return {undefined}
*/
function cellClick(e) {
    changeCellBackground(e);
    if (currentNum) {

        e.textContent = currentNum;
    }
    lastSelectedCell = e;
}
/* */
function changeCellBackground(currentcell) {
    // если пользователь несколько раз нажал на 1 ячейку, то 
    // ничего не делаем
        currentcell.style.background = cellSelectBackgroundColor;
        if (lastSelectedCell){
            lastSelectedCell.style.background = cellBackgroundColor;
        }
}
```

[image: Исчезновение содержимого]

Я подозреваю, что строчка e.textContent = currentNum; затирает абсолютно все содержимое ячейки, даже невидимое, но как это обойти, я не знаю. Буду благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно затирает, тут надо получать  детей того элемента, по которому кликнули и дальше работать с детьми. Вообще странная верстка, зачем столько кода???

Comment: @СергейВ. а как можно сократить код? Я же решил эту задачу путем создания тэга span, в который я записывал текущее значение.

Comment: span? А он тут причем? ГДЕ он в вопросе? Вот таких ячеек td, как в вопросе, сколько всего? Или одна?

Comment: Его не было в вопросе, потому что я его ещё не добавил в game-ceil. Таких ячеек всего 81. Я уже решил вопрос, спасибо за обратную связь.